# How does predict() work when newdata parameter is missed?

Tags: r, model

I was recently learning about hurdle models. I found a blog with these codes.

```
library(AER)
data("NMES1988")
nmes <- NMES1988[, c(1, 6:8, 13, 15, 18)]
plot(table(nmes$visits))
mod1 <- glm(visits ~. , data = nmes, family = "poisson")

mu <- predict(mod1, type = "response")

exp <- sum(dpois(x=0, lambda = mu))
```

The newdata parameter is missed in predict() function. Will this function do prediction based on the old data nmes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it uses the original data, i.e. yields the `fitted.values` (yhat). Check:

```
mu <- predict(mod1, type = "response")
mu2 <- predict(mod1, type = "response", newdata=nmes)
mu3 <- mod1$fitted.values

identical(mu, mu2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(mu, mu3)
# [1] TRUE
```